# When does RobotFramework output XML get produced?

Tags: xml, robotframework

I'm trying to parse the XML produced by RobotFramework to deduce the current status of a test.

I'm having mixed results, where sometimes the XML is produced during the execution of a test suite and other times it is produced on completion.

In the below example, I can see results printed to stdout, but the XML is not produced until after the suite finishes.  I have other test suites that seem to produce XML while the suite is running.

Here is an example test I've set up, along with an example keyword (In ExampleLib.py):

```
from time import sleep
class ExampleLib(object):

    def long_running_test(self):
        sleep(random.randint(5,10))
        return True
```

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Example long running tests - XML is not produced until all are finished.
Library           ExampleLib.py
Library           Collections

*** Test Cases ***
LongTest1
    ${results}=     long running test
    Should be true  ${results}

LongTest2
    ${results}=     long running test
    Should be true  ${results}

LongTest3
    ${results}=     long running test
    Should be true  ${results}

LongTest4
    ${results}=     long running test
    Should be true  ${results}

LongTest5
    ${results}=     long running test
    Should be true  ${results}
```

Any help or advice, perhaps there is a better way to find the status of a currently running test?

Comment: _"where sometimes the XML is produced during the execution of a test suite "_ - I don't think that's possible. Robot writes the xml only after all tests have finished running. Can you show a case where the xml is being generated before robot finishes?

Comment: If you need the status of a test while robot is running, you should not be trying to parse the xml. Instead, you should use a [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) which lets you run a function before and after every test suite, test case, and/or keyword runs.

Comment: Hi Bryan - I'll look into the listener, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
I'm struggling to get a minimum reproducible example, however I have a test suite with the keyword, "wait until keyword succeeds" which seems to be producing XML part way through the test.  The XML appears to be incomplete, i.e. doesn't have the closing tags.  My initial plan was to parse this XML to get the current status of a robotframework test.